# Why does 7-Zip deflate 257 and 258 word sizes?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

Compression word sizes are usually powers of 2. Yet, 7-Zip has some exceptions:

- Deflate has both 256 and 258 word sizes.
- Deflate64 has both 256 and 257 word sizes.

These seem like such trivial and strange increases. What's the reason/purpose for them?

Here's a pic of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7-Zip doesn't actually show all of the word sizes that Deflate and Deflate64 are capable of. It only shows a select sample. Deflate is actually capable of all whole number increments between 3-258. Since pattern matching isn't possible or useful with just 1-2 variables, those quantities are skipped. Thus, the word size span of Deflate actually is a power of 2. Since "1" and "2" aren't possible word size choices for Deflate, you -2 from the max size of 258, which equals 256.

As for Deflate64, it's capable of all whole number increments between 3-257. 258 is actually used as an extension flag to increase the word size range from 3-65538. However, 7-Zip simply doesn't make use of this feature. Anyway, if you -2 from 65538, you get 65536, which is also a power of 2. Interestingly, however, Deflate64 might be improved if the extension flag were to cover the ranges 258-65793 instead, since  3-257 are already covered.